How to launch a Spring Boot 3.x application programmatically from Java code
I would like to start a Spring Boot 3.x application, packaged in a "fat" jar by the spring-boot-maven-plugin, programmatically from Java code. The obvious approach, similar to what the JVM does when you run java -jar ..., is to create a new class loader pointing at the fat jar, use it to load the jar's main class, and invoke the "main" method. This works for a Spring Boot 2.x application, but not for 3.x. I'd like to understand why.
Andy Wilkinson gave example code similar to this in a Github issue. (I've added the "null" second argument to the URLClassLoader constructor, which isolates it from the current class loader.)
void launchApp(File fatJar, String... args) throws Exception {
    var classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {fatJar.toURI().toURL()}, null);
    var mainClass = classLoader.loadClass(getMainClassName(fatJar));
    var mainMethod = mainClass.getMethod("main", String[].class);
    mainMethod.invoke(null, new Object[] {args});
}

String getMainClassName(File fatJar) throws IOException {
    try (JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(fatJar)) {
        return jarFile.getManifest().getMainAttributes().getValue(Attributes.Name.MAIN_CLASS);
    }
}

Putting this code in a trivial Java application works fine to launch a Spring Boot 2.x application packaged in a fat jar. But when used to launch a Spring Boot 3.x application, it fails with:
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: nested

So clearly the tooling for reading the content of the "fat jar" isn't getting set up correctly.
Why is this? Why does java -jar ... successfully start up a Spring Boot 3.x application, while the above code that sets up a URLClassLoader does not?

Found this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/38948 on their GitHub Issues page. Maybe it helps somehow?
